# Backpacking in southern NY or PA

Tags: hiking, backpacking, trails

All-

I'm looking for a good 25-30 mile backpacking trail in southern NY or PA. I've looked into Allegany State Park and National Forest, but couldn't find a loop that would keep us out of campgrounds.

Are there any good loops in the system of state parks to the east of Allegany?

Comment: Can you add more details to your question? One thing that can help is what kind of trail you're looking for - for example, how long, what time of year, how many days, where you plan on sleeping (especially if you want to avoid campgrounds). That will help people to know whether their proposed route is suitable. Another thing is which resources you've used already to try to find a trail, so people can suggest resources you might not be familiar with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some great backpacking loops in Northren PA.
Off the top of my head I know of the Allegheny Front Trail and The Olde Loggers Path
Check out http://www.midatlantichikes.com/pa.htm
and also http://www.pahikes.com/
for some great PA hikes

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Devil's Path in the Catskills](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_Path_%28Catskills%29):

[Long Path](http://www.nynjtc.org/region/long-path)

A little further north in the Adirondacks is the [Northville-Placid Trail](http://www.nptrail.org):

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered the [Finger Lakes Trail](https://fingerlakestrail.org/)?  It's certainly long enough, and has lean-tos along most of its length.  There aren't a lot of loops, but you may be able to arrange a one-way with return by car or public transport.  (In particular, the section around Ithaca crosses county bus routes at several places.)